# How to deal with discontinuous points when proving that step functions are dense in $PC[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

This question is a follow-up to my previous question: [How does one prove that a space is dense in another under some norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859619/how-does-one-prove-that-a-space-is-dense-in-another-under-some-norm)

I figured out a way to solve (part of) the exercise.
Given some function $f\in PC[a,b]$, my argument relies on the continuity of $f$ to prove that there exists some sequence $f_N\subset S[a,b]$ such that $$\lim_{N\to \infty} d(f,f_N)=\lim_{N\to\infty} ||f-f_N||_\infty=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup_{x\ \in\ [a,b]} |f(x)-f_N(x)|=0 $$
However, the exercise that I am trying to solve asks for a proof that $S[a,b]$ is dense in $PC[a,b]$, the space of all bounded *piecewise continuous* functions on $[a,b]$. My assumption of continuity seems to be at tension with the fact that $f$ should be allowed to be discontinuous at finitely many points.

I was wondering what the standard procedure is for dealing with the finitely many points where $f\in PC[a,b]$ may be discontinuous. One possibility I considered can be described as "starting a new step in the step function at each of the finitely many $x_j$ where one encounters discontinuity of $f(x)$", but this is clearly not rigorous enough.

**Update:** After some discussion with T.A.E., he suggested that it should be possible to add some $s\in S[a,b]$ to any piecewise continuous function to reduce the problem to the continuous case, which I solved already. However, I am unclear how to make this argument precise (doesn't a step function just 'shift the discontinuity'?). Any suggestions or alternatives are more than welcome.

Comment: There's a problem with the formulation because in order to discuss $S[a,b]$ being dense *in* $C[a,b]$, you would have to have $S[a,b]\subseteq C[a,b]$, which you don't have. I assume there is some larger space $X$ with $S[a,b]\subseteq X$ and $C[a,b]\subseteq X$ where $C[a,b]\subseteq S[a,b]^{c}$. What is that larger space $X$?

Comment: @T.A.E. Thank you for your reply. Your suggestion certainly sounds reasonable. However, if you have a look at problem 8a of this problem set: http://math.uga.edu/~clayton/courses/608/608_1.pdf, does this not seem to contradict what you said? Feel free to point out any blatant errors of mine, I am quite new to analysis.

Comment: @T.A.E. The exercise I am trying to solve calls for a proof that $S[a,b]$ is dense in $PC[a,b]$. I just thought I'd proven that $S[a,b]$ is dense in $C[a,b]$ because I assumed that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ in my proof. This may be wrong.

Comment: @T.A.E. I rewrote part of my question so that this confusion about $C[a,b]$ does not arise. Is the question sensible in this form? And would you happen to know an answer to it?

Comment: Now the formulation can make sense because it could make sense that $S[a,b]\subseteq PC[a,b]$. The problem with piecewise continuous functions is that $f(x-0)$, $f(x+0)$ and $f(x)$ are not necessarily related. So it's convenient to settle on a convention where $f(x-0)=f(x)$ or $f(x)=f(x+0)$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x-0)+f(x+0))$. The problem is that every point counts in a sup norm. But the normalization is irrelevant if you are you using an $L^{\infty}$ essential sup norm. Are you using the essential sup norm?

Comment: @T.A.E. In the book that I am using, $PC[a,b]$ is defined as 'the family of bounded piecewise continuous functions on $[a,b]$ which are continuous from the right and for which the limit from the left exists everywhere and is equal to the limit from the right everywhere except for finitely many points'. Does this help in formulating a way to complete the proof?

Comment: You can use a max norm if all the functions in $S[a,b]$ and in $PC[a,b]$ have limits $f(x+0)$, $f(x-0)$ where possible, and satisfy $f(x)=f(x+0)$ where possible. Then, for $p \in PC[a,b]$ there should exist $s \in S[a,b]$ so that $p-s$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, which reduces the approximation problem to one of finding $s \in S[a,b]$ to approximate $f \in C[a,b]$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15611/discussion-between-danu-and-t-a-e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the functions in $PC[a,b]$ and in $S[a,b]$ are normalized so that
$$
            f(x+0)=f(x),\;\;\; a \le x < b.
$$
All of the functions are required to be continuous at $a$ using this normalization. But these funtions may be discontinuous at $b$. If $y \in (a,b]$ is a point of discontinuity of $f \in PC[a,b]$, then
$$
          s(x) = f(y-0)\chi_{[a,y)}(x)+f(y)\chi_{[y,b]}(x)
$$
is a normalized function in $S[a,b]$ with $y$ as the only point of discontinuity; furthermore, $s(y+0)=f(y)=f(y+0)$ and $s(y-0)=f(y-0)$. Therefore $f-s$ is a normalized function in $PC[a,b]$ that is continuous at $y$; $f-s$ has the same jumps and discontinuities as $f$ in $[a,b]\setminus\{y\}$. Continuing by finite induction, you obtain $s \in S[a,b]$ such that $g=f-s$ is continuous. Because $g$ is continuous, then it is uniformly continuous, and, for every $\epsilon > 0$, you can find points $a=x_{0} < x_{1} < \cdots < x_{n}=b$ such that
$$
    s_{\epsilon}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}c_{j}\chi_{[x_{j-1},x_{j})}(x)+c_{n}\chi_{[x_{n-1},x_{n}]}(x)
$$
satisfies $|s_{\epsilon}(x)-g(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. It follows that $|f-s-s_{\epsilon}| < \epsilon$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Beautiful. Of course, 'shift the discontinuity' to $a$!